# Java: Saving a String to a file

Tags: java, string, file, save, actionlistener

In the game that I'm working on I have a `String` that displays the score, the problem is that the code save the `String` to the file. I wan't the file to save the score constantly because the score will update as you play the game. Therefor I run the method from a swing Timer like this.

```
        Timer timer = new Timer(1, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                save();
            } 
        });
        timer.start();
```

The save method looks like this and it should work because I have used the exact same code for a text program I made awhile ago.

```
    public void save(){
        try{
            getScore = new File("Score.dat");
            scoreFile = new FileOutputStream(getScore);
            byte[] saveScore = score.getBytes();
            scoreFile.write(saveScore);
            scoreFile.close();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){

        }catch(IOException ex){

        }
    }
```

I have two buttons in the starting screen for the game `New Game` and `Continue`. I have made it so that if you press `New Game` the file will update it's text to 0 and if you press `Continue` the code will go on as normal and the score will equal to what is displayed in the file. This is the `ActionListener` for the two buttons.

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    Object command = e.getSource(); 
    if(command.equals(newGame)){
        try{
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("Score.dat"));
            pw.print("0");
            pw.close();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException ex){

        }
        startGame = true;
    }
    if(command.equals(contGame)){
        startGame = true;
    }
}
```

The file is created just normal and I don't get any errors but the file doesn't update it will always be a 0 inside it. I have tried to use `PrintWriter` instead of `FileOutputStream` because it works for setting the file's text to 0 but when I use it with `pw.print(score);` my file explorer crash and I have to restart my comuter.

**EDIT:**

I have figured out what the problem is but I don't know how to solve it. When I print out the score the result will be as following: 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30 (if the number inside the file is 0, if it would be 50 you would replace all the 0's with 50) and so on.

So as you see there's only a 25% chance for the file to update the score. I have no idea why this is happening because I don't see any place in my code that could cause this.

This is the code that loads the score back.

```
    public void load(){
        try{
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Score.dat"));
            score = br.readLine();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException ex){

        }catch(IOException ex){

        }
    }
```

This method is runned once by having `load();` in the `public Player()` method (`Player` is the name of the class).

Comment: have you tried to flush() the stream?

Comment: I would actually print the exceptions thrown/caught here:

    }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){

    }catch(IOException ex){

    }

Comment: You want to save the file every 1 ms? are you ok?!? Save the file everytime your score changesm, it makes no sense to save a file every 1 ms!

Comment: @BrianAgnew I have done that and nothing get printed because the exceptions are never thrown

Comment: Have you made sure that you check whats in the file before you start a new game and after you have played the game for a bit. I ask because nowhere do i see you reading the score back into the game when you continue.

Comment: @ns47731 I didn't post the code for loading the file back in again because that isn't the problem. And I know that the score never updates because I have played through the hole game (it's roughly 5 mins at the moment) and then manually checked inside the file to see if the score is correct but it will still be a 0 in the file.

Comment: your score is in a string ? looks like your appending to the string and not over writing it. try my answer

Answer (score 0):

I hate to suggest this, but are you certain that your `score` variable is non-zero in the `save()` method?  You might consider putting a line in there to print the value of `score` for debugging purposes, or check the value in your debugger.  There is nothing obviously wrong with this method, and it does work without a `flush()`, as a `PrintWriter` will autoflush on `close()` as defined in `Writer`.

As backslash noted, you probably want to increase the sleep time on your timer, one ms is really short.

Comment: When I printed out the score this was the result:

Comment: Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 10
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 20
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 40
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 40
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0

Comment: Why is the score 0 between me shooting the enemies. When I shoot an enemy the score sould supposedly go up with 10 so it seems like it will only be 10 when I shoot a enemy and then be 0 until I shoot another enemy

Comment: I would bet money that you're inadvertently over-writing the value in score with 0 in some part of your game loop.  If you're using Eclipse you can right click on the score variable and select "show references", which should show you everywhere you make a reference to this variable.  You might want to check the setter method for it as well, if you have one.

Comment: I don't see any place in my code that set the score to 0, but I saw now that it's precisely 4 0's between every 10, 20, 30... so it probably have to do with something in the swing Timer's for my game

Comment: I just manually set the score inside the file to 50 just to see if it would still be the same pattern and now it prints this out:

Comment: Score: 50
Score: 50
Score: 50
Score: 50
Score: 80
Score: 50
Score: 50
Score: 50
Score: 50
Score: 90
Score: 50
Score: 50
Score: 50
Score: 50
Score: 90
Score: 50
Score: 50
Score: 50

Comment: I'd take a look at the code that reads the score back in from the file in that case.  That is likely to be the source of over-writing the score variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could be having sync issues. make just one method that takes the score and write it to file. Call this method on new game, continue, close window (if it is a java frame) , and in your timer. But make the timer at least 250 milli seconds

```
synchronized void save(int score) {
    PrintWriter pw = null;//any resource with IO should be in a finally block to close
    try {
        pw = new PrintWriter(new File("Score.dat"));
        pw.print("" + score);
        pw.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("save err " + ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
        // or better get a logger
        // logger.log(Level.WARNING,"save err " + ex ,ex);

    }finally{
        if (pw != null) {
            try {
                pw.close();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                logger.log(Level.FINER, "err close :pw" , e);
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: better to keep your score var as a int or long, edit your code for read accordingly